# jBPM 6 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, drools, jbpm

I have just started my working with jBPM6. I can make new jBPM Process with "a simply hello world process", but I don't know how to use it and i'm looking for some tutorial, in which I can see how to use jBPM in Eclipse, some example etc. Can anyone help me? It will be helpful for me if some tutorial/user guide show step by step how to do something in Eclipse with jBPM.

Greetings
rizon

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to run the default hello world project, then you might not have included all the required jar files.

Just include all jar files and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think jBPM distribution that is downloaded from jBPM site contains complete distribution with embedded JBoss AS, H2 database and Eclipse environment. By running ant install.demo it downloades complete distro.
Try to do the following:

1. download jbpm installer
2. unzip it in some directory and run "ant install.demo". This will download all the necessary files to your machine
3. run "ant start.demo". This will run JBoss AS, H2 database and Eclipse
4. on finish, type "ant stop.demo"

Details are described in install.html file.

Afterwards, if you want to run Eclipse only, simply type "ant start.eclipse".